# tkinter interação entre janelas

Tags: tkinter

estou tendo um problema quero abrir um arquivo chamado vapor.py(interface) separado da tela inicial, quando eu clicar na opção vapor do menu,só que não está dando certo,não está abrindo, e quando abre, essa tela abre dentro do menu e eu não quero isso quero que abra separado, alguém poderia me ajudar, o arquivo vapor.py está no mesmo diretório por isso que não coloquei o caminho

```
from tkinter import *


def primeirajanela():
    exec(open("vapor.py").read())

#tela inicial do software
ap = Tk()
ap.title('SOFTWARES')
ap.geometry('1300x600')
ap.configure(background='#d2d4a9')
ap.minsize(1300,600)
ap.maxsize(1300,600)

barrademenus = Menu(ap)
menuestado = Menu(barrademenus,tearoff=0)
menuestado.add_command(label='Vapor',command=primeirajanela)
menuestado.add_command(label='Mistura de Vapor')
menuestado.add_command(label='Líquido')
menuestado.add_command(label='Mistura de Líquido')
menuestado.add_command(label='Sair',command=ap.quit)
barrademenus.add_cascade(label='Cálculos',menu=menuestado)

ap.config(menu=barrademenus)

ap.mainloop()
```